# VBA Code for drop-down list with dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro for multiple drop-downs in "n" cells (let's say 100) in a column. The ranges (drop-down values) for these drop-downs have to be picked from a table with the same number of rows (100 in our case).

I am unable to run the `for` loop for the formula part (highlighted below). I want the macro to pick `D2:H2` range for `i=2`, `D3:H3` for `i=3`, and so on. How do I do it? Is there any alternative to this?

```
Sub S_Dropdown3()
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    wks.Select
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 101
        With Range("B" & i).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, **Formula1:="=Sheet2!D2:H2"**
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub S_Dropdown3()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
wks.Activate

For i = 2 To 101
    With wks.Range("B" & i).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!D" & i & ":H" & i
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Implemented changes:

1. Code formatting / indentation
2. Implementing full qualification to ensure that `Sheet1` refers to `Sheet1` in the workbook from which the macro is run (in case that more than one Excel file is open).
3. Sheets cannot be `.Selected` only ranges get selected. Sheets can only be `.Activated`. Earlier versions of Excel don't mind. Never versions of Excel will throw an error with that line.
4. Fully qualifying `.Range("B" & i)`.
5. Finally, making the formula modular as requested in the initial post.